# Keep service running in background without showing notification

Tags: android, service, android-service, background-service

I'm developing a messaging application and I need my service to keep running in background even if the application was closed but without showing a notification in navigation bar and start when the phone is started and restart itself when it is closed for any reason, I know this question has been asked before but I can find nothing to do this, I just want it to be like whatsapp or facebook or bbm services, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> I need my service to keep running in background even if the application was closed but without showing a notification in navigation bar and start when the phone is started and restart itself when it is closed for any reason

That is not strictly possible.

You are welcome to return `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from your service's `onStartCommand()` method. Android will still terminate your process due to old age and low memory conditions from time to time, but Android will eventually restart those services. What percentage of the time your process will be running will depend on a variety of factors, not the least of which being how much system RAM the Android device has.

Better yet, you are welcome to use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to deliver your messages to your app. This way, you do not need a service running all of the time. Your app can get control when a message arrives, do some work for that message, then go away.

> I just want it to be like whatsapp or facebook or bbm services

BlackBerry Messenger uses `startForeground()` and [has an icon in the status bar as a result](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bbm).

Comment: my application is instant messaging application and I need to be running this service in background as it handles so many things not just the messages that user receive and I don't want any restricts on the number of messages that I send as I heard that GCM sends only 1000 requests per day, I know also that bbm use foreground notification but it has the option to make it disappear also in the setting of the application

Comment: @KareemEssamGaber: "as I heard that GCM sends only 1000 requests per day" -- that is incorrect. "it handles so many things not just the messages that user receive" -- you are welcome to believe what you want. I cannot think of a good reason to have a continuously-running service for an instant messaging app, if that app is using GCM for inbound messages.

Comment: I appreciate help but I don't know how to use GCM I tried to read google's documentations and so many tutorials on how to program my server to send, recieve and handle requests with GCM but I still don't know how to do it, do you have any suggestions for an easy and efficient tutorial for bigginers?

Comment: @KareemEssamGaber: I have not looked for a GCM tutorial recently.